# nightwatch :session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 81

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js, nightwatch

Anyone know how to fix this error on the terminal when you run a test in nightwatch.
My Chrome version is the 83, but I don't know if I have to change something on the package-json or update something

Answer (score 1):

You have to download and update your version of the chromedriver if it's Chrome you're testing https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads, and if you're testing an Edge version that uses Chromium, you want https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/.

You may or may not have to update package.json to point to those newer versions.